# How to send a request for token from graphql to python api?

Tags: python, node.js, django, api, graphql

I need to send an Authorization request from graphql to a python API so that I can communicate with the Python API. In this request, I need to send the user's username and password with `Authorization` header and receive token that will be used in further communication. I dont know how to send this request. I have created the schema to communicate otherwise but can't figure out how to add this part.

Here is the rest of my code :

`Schema.js`

```
import {
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
} from 'graphql';

import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:9000/api';

function getUserByURL(relativeURL) {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}${relativeURL}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => json.user)
}

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    description: '...',

    fields: () => ({
        firstName: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (user) => user.first_name
        },
        lastName: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (user) => user.last_name
        },
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        username: {type: GraphQLString},
        blockchain_address: {type: GraphQLString},      
    }),
});

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: '...',

    fields: () => ({
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: {type: GraphQLString,}
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => 
                getUserByURL(`/users/${args.id}/`),
        }       
    })
});

export default new GraphQLSchema({
    query: QueryType,
});
```

`index.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql';

import schema from './schema';


const app = express();

app.use(graphQLHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(8080);
```